# Understanding 気軽に見る

Tags: meaning

Middle-aged man recently brought a smartphone and he is trying to get used to it:

[image]

I am puzzled by the usage of 気軽に見る here. It means "to look carefreely"? It doesn't make any sense to me in this context. I might be misunderstanding the meaning of 気軽.

Answer (score 2):

That may be a slight difference of 気軽に from carefreeness (usually positive?). It can be used as "without thinking  too much", which can be positive or non-positive.

For example, 気軽に試せる means something you can try without too much thinking e.g. because it is cheap or readily available in some sense. The phrase as a whole is positive.

On the other hand, 気軽に見る is not necessarily positive. It is more literally "watch without enough thinking/caution in mind". That is, it should be close to "care**less**ly".